# I am having problems with download vcard for a website

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a downloadable vcard for a website (The website is currently local so I cannot show you the frontend). What I have done is within an about section I want the vcard to show beside my social media icons. The issue is its not aligning correctly. I clicked on the download which opens a new tab and it doesnt download. I believe the problem is with the href code

my code is as before. (I am using my LinkedIn image for testing). I have research on this and I see some apply JS code but I prefer not to use js or php.

```css
.card {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 2em auto;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 1em;
  overflow: auto;
  background-image: url(../../assets/img/linkedin-icon.png);
  

  a {
    padding: 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #00ffbb;
    background: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
    
    &:hover {
      color: #000;
      background: #00ffbb;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!--/ #About -->
            <section id="about" name="about"></section>
            <div id="colourblock">                       
                <div class="row">
                    
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <div class="aboutprofile">
                                        <img class="center" src="../../assets/img/about-section.png" alt="About" >
                                    </div>
                    </div>
        
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sitDonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sitDonec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit.
                            </p>
                            <br>
                            <p>
    <a href="www.linkedin.com" target="_blank"><img src="../../assets/img/linkedin-icon.png" alt="About" ></a>
                                <a href="www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><img src="../../assets/img/twitter-icon.png" alt="Twitter" ></a>
    <a href="mailto:imtiazabbas02@gmail.com"><img src="../../assets/img/email-profile.png" alt="Email" ></a>
                                <div class="card">
    
    <a href=" ../../assets/Imtiaz_Abbas.vcf" id="dl" target="_blank" download="Imtiaz_Abbas.vcf">Download contact</a>
  </div>


                            </p>
                    </div>
        
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 issues. First the CSS issue. As you are obviously a beginner I would suggest you build the link to you VCard the same way as you do it with twitter and linkedin. Do not use a div, nor a background, just do it with a link.

Second issue is the vcf file download. I understand you want to avoid complex solution. The simplest solution is to add a new mime type to your .htaccess file (you can create on in the root of your web if you don't have one). You should add this line to your htacess file:

```
AddType text/x-vcard .vcf
```

You could also read this thread on Stackoverflow: [vCard .vcf file download browser support - godaddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116772/vcard-vcf-file-download-browser-support-godaddy)